# NavigationView menu item color not changing on API 15

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm new to StackOverFlow and this is my first question here. Pardon me if i make any mistakes.
I have a `NavigationView` inside `DrawerLayout` which looks something like this

**DrawerLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_selector"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_icon_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_text_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_screen"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_screen_drawer">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Below is my nav_item_selector, nav_icon_color, nav_text_color classes

**nav_item_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/fb_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

**nav_icon_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="#2e9f68" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

**nav_text_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#b5edd2" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="#222222" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

This is working fine for API > 15 but on API 15 only `itemBackground` is working but in `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor` `statePressed` is not working. Don't know why.
I also tried to set this programmatically in my Activity

**MainActivity**

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
};

int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.RED,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.BLUE
};

navigationView.setItemTextColor(new ColorStateList(states,colors));
```

Below are the screenshots for API 15 and API 19. I've tested this in API 16 as well and it was working fine.

Not Working in API 15:
[image: Not Working in API 15]

Working in API > 15:
[image: Working in API > 15]

Comment: So at the end i found no solution for this. Even here no one commented or answered this. So i'm assuming that it can't be achieved using this approach on API 15. If someone finds the solution to this or interested to know more about this issue can comment below.